# Filter out unnecessary words (i.e. words without connotation)

Tags: c++, nlp

So I'm working on a project where I have to process large amounts of amazon reviews. How would I go about shortening each review to a couple of essential words only? Like only words with strong connotations positive and negative. Thanks!

Comment: What if you make a dictionary with predefined  words to sort them? I mean if it contains "I like" or "bad / good quality" and you sort them to different sections. You can just read a bunch of text from positive reviews and search for the most used adjective with the right context and sort them that way.

Answer (score 0):

In nlp this is usually called sentiment analysis.
First of all, looking for positive or non positive words can be challenging due to ambiguity. In amazon reviews you also have rating - this means your data is labeled (so that a 1 star rating indicates that the review is negative, and a 5 star rating is a positive review).

I suggest, instead of looking for words that correlate positively with the sentiment, to remove the words that do not effect the sentiment. i.e. cleaning the data. 
in nlp, the most common ways are stemming, and stop-word removal. 
after you have done these two, you would have removed most of the noise. 
Also, you would benefit by extracting features from the data, a common feature is called tf-idf.